# How to say "many hours before something" in simpler words and make it sound less formal?

Tags: time

> They let me check in many hours before the official checkin time.

This phrase sounds a bit formal to me. I'd like to simplify it, but the only other option that comes to my mind is "long before". However, as by the Longman dictionary, the "long before" phrase sounds like when one has a much longer period in view:

> This all happened long before you were born.

Ideas?

Comment: Yes, long before or well before or very colloquially way before

Comment: several hours before / a few hours before / some hours before / many hours before / long before ... (The meaning/duration of "long" is very context dependent; it seems fine in the case.)

Answer (score 3):

You could try "way before". (inf.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try “several hours prior.”

Answer (score 0):

> They let me check in many hours before the official checkin time.

If this sounds formal to you, then it's likely that using **long before** instead of **many hours before** will sound similarly formal:

> They let me check in long before the official checkin time.

Regardless of the the use of **long before**, I think part of the formality is in the **X before Y** phrasing itself.

I would try removing the comparative in order to simplify the entire sentence:

> They let me check in quite early.